# TabColor is not set in ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview

I am using "BottomNavigationBar" in xamarin.forms to implement bottom Bar. I customize it according to the below link ["https://github.com/HoussemDellai/BottomBar-Xamarin-Forms"](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/BottomBar-Xamarin-Forms). I have not implemented direct nuget of [ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF/).

Version detail
xamarin.forms : 3.0.482510
BottomNavigationBar : 1.4.0.3
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design : 25.4.0.2

**Question :
TabColor is not set according to the sample. default color is white.**

Code :

```
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Inika.Views.BottomBar.BottomBarPages"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Inika.Views.Category;assembly=Inika"
            xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:Inika.Views.BottomBar;assembly=Inika">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <pages:Product Title="PRODUCT" Icon="ic_favorites.png" xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#5D4037"/>
    <ContentPage Title="APPLICATION" Icon="ic_nearby.png" xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#7B1FA2"/>
    <ContentPage Title="IMAGES" Icon="ic_restaurants.png" xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#FF5252"/>
</xf:BottomBarPage>
```

> but xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#FF5252" is not working as
>   expected

**Tabbar.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

**My custom render is also called perfectly. I can not figure out. In the sample, everything works properly but when I implemented the same thing in my project it is not working.**

> ***Should I use version v1.0.3 of ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF instead of v1.0.2?***

Comment: Can you share custom  Renderer code?

Comment: Custom render is same as below link https://github.com/HoussemDellai/BottomBar-Xamarin-Forms/blob/master/BottomBarDemo/BottomBarDemo.Android/BottomBar/Renderers/BottomBarPageRenderer.cs

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use FixedMode and set color of Background or Tab active or inactive using below code in your renderer for Android.

```
                _bottomBar.UseFixedMode();
                _bottomBar.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                _bottomBar.SetOnTabClickListener(this);
                _bottomBar.SetTypeFace("SF-UI-Text-Regular.ttf");
                _bottomBar.SetActiveTabColor("#434A4F");
                _bottomBar.SetFixedInactiveIconColor("#d0d0d0");
                _bottomBar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Violet);

                UpdateTabs();
                UpdateBarBackgroundColor();
                UpdateBarTextColor();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "SetActiveTabColor" and "SetBackgroundColor" is not working in fixed mode even normal mode. My question is why "xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor " is not working in XMAL.